# How do i fetch a certain field from the database from only knowing the id?

Tags: php, mysql

```
foreach ($cart_array as $id => $quantity){
    $itemName = ($id['ProductName']);
    $itemPrice = $id['ProductPrice']; 

    $addItem = "INSERT INTO order_items ( order_number, ProductName, Quantity, Price ) VALUES ('1', '$itemName', '$quantity', '$itemPrice')"; 
    //$addItem = "INSERT INTO order_items VALUES ('one', '$itemName', '$quantity', '$itemPrice')";  

    if (!($result =  mysqli_query ($connection, $addItem))) 
        die("Error creating item in addItem Query in process order"); 
}
```

My `itemName` and `itemPrice` are not working. How do I assign a certain row of data to a variable from knowing the ID? For example, I want to assign the name of each product `$id` to the variable `$itemName`, therefore allowing me to insert it into a database.

Comment: `SELECT yourfield FROM yourtable WHERE idfield=$id`?

Comment: Can you post the results if you do this: `var_dump($cart_array);`

Comment: i cant do a query inside a foreach loop because it inserts the query into the field instead of the result of the query

Answer (score 0):

What's the structure of your array?

You're extracting $cart_array as $key => $value.  You're probably looking for, in your case, $quantity[ProductName].

Try:

```
foreach ($cart_array AS $id => $quantity){

print ("$id<br />");
print ("<pre>");
print_r($quantity);
print ("</pre>");
print ("<hr />");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are referencing your array elements incorrectly.  Rather than do

```
foreach ($cart_array as $id => $quantity){
    $itemName = $id['ProductName'];
    $itemPrice = $id['ProductPrice'];
    //....
}
```

You need to do

```
foreach ($cart_array as $id => $quantity){
    $itemName = $quantity['ProductName'];
    $itemPrice = $quantity['ProductPrice'];
```

Or if you want to get a specific row based on the `$id` like you ask you can do

```
$id = 2; //Set this to the product id you need
$itemName = $cart_array[$id]['ProductName'];
```

Comment: I need the $id to be the key in the array?

Comment: I tried referencing it to quantity and it still deosnt input the correct data.?